# Empty array when trying to scrape YouTube main page with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, web-scraping, cheerio

so I'm playing around with request and cheerio npm's and I can't seem to find a solution, why does it keep giving me empty arrays. I used same code when I scraped reddit and it worked like a charm, but when I use it on YouTube or any other page it doesn't work.

```
var request = require('request'),
cheerio = require('cheerio'),
fs = require('fs'),
urls = [];

request('https://www.youtube.com/', function(err,resp,body) {
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('a.yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer', 'primary').each(function() {
            var url = $(this);
            urls.push(url);
    });
```

And this is my reddit code (works fine)

```
var request = require('request'),
cheerio = require('cheerio'),
fs = require('fs'),
urls = [];

request('http://www.reddit.com/', function(err,resp,body) {
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('a.title', '#siteTable').each(function() {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if(url.indexOf('imgur.com')!= -1) {
                urls.push(url);
            }
        });

    Output Example: [ 'http://i.imgur.com/WVrmZ9j.gifv',
  'http://i.imgur.com/T0BchYC.gifv',
  'http://imgur.com/u59lzux' ]
```

Comment: Download the HTML first and check whether desired HTML tags are there or not.

Comment: When I download HTML only, then theres no such tags. But if I download complete web page, then there are all tags.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML that cheerio loads for youtube is different.

Do `res.send($.html());` to check the HTML structure and target it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get some information from YouTube, you can't use Cheerio. Instead, you need to use browser automation, e.g. [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) because YouTube dynamically loads content on the page via JavaScript. In the code below I show you how you can do this (also check [it on the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Scrape-YouTube-main-page-urls-with-NodeJS#index.js)):

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const mainPageUrl = "https://www.youtube.com";

async function getUrls() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60000);
  await page.goto(mainPageUrl);
  await page.waitForSelector("#contents");
  const urls = await page.$$eval("a#thumbnail", (els) => {
    return els.map(el => el.getAttribute('href') ? "https://www.youtube.com" + el.getAttribute('href') : undefined).filter((el) => el)
  });
  await browser.close();
  return urls;
}

getUrls().then(console.log);
```

Output

```json
[
   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rliFQ0qyAM",
   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36YnV9STBqc",
   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1_hYe3hhjE",
   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uv6iK2kS3qQ",
   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUGWLAFqYUc",
   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17TYygDfr28",
   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2isYuQZMbdU",
    ...and other results
]
```

You can read more about scraping YouTube from my blog posts:

- [Web scraping YouTube search video results with Nodejs](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-youtube-search-video-results-with-nodejs/)
- [Web scraping YouTube secondary search results with Nodejs](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-youtube-secondary-search-results-with-nodejs/)
- [Web scraping YouTube video page with Nodejs](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-youtube-video-page-with-nodejs/)